# Mockito: how to pass method call as a parameter

Tags: java, testing, junit, functional-programming, mockito

I want to create a method that will generate `OngoingStubbing` for N times to enable stubbing mocks iteratively. How can I pass, method call, for instance: `mock.getId()` as a parameter to a method?

I have used next approach, but it doesn't work, it passes result of method invocation

```
public class MyMock {

   private String id;

   public MyMock(String id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   
   public String getId() {
       return this.id;
   }
}

...

@Test
public void stubExample() {
   MyMock mock = Mockito.mock(MyMock.class);
   List<MyMock> mocksList = stubbingMethod(() -> mock.getId());
   Assert.assertEquals(3, mocksList.size());
}

private List<MyMock> stubbingMethod(Supplier<String> sup) {
   Mockito.when(sup.get()).thenReturn("id1")
                .thenReturn("id2")
                .thenReturn("id3");

   return List.of(
          new MyMock(sup.get()),
          new MyMock(sup.get()),
          new MyMock(sup.get()));
}
```

And every time throws NullPointerException.

Thanks!

Comment: How can it throw NPE if it does not even compile? `List.of(sup.get(), sup.get(), sup.get())` is a list of Strings, while the `stubbingMethod` should return a list of MyMocks

Comment: @Lesiak my fault. edited

Comment: Your code works fine for me - I get a list of 3 MyMock instances, with ids: id1, id2 and id3. Please share the stack trace of your NPE.

Comment: @Lesiak, Sorry, problem was resolved. description is incorrect, thank you for your participation

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem, description is a little bit ambiguous. So, for iterative stubbing use next:

```
public void stub(List<MyMock> mocks, List<String> ids) {
     IntStream.range(0, mocks.size()).boxed()
               .map(index ->
                       Mockito.when(mock.getId()).thenReturn(ids.get(index)));
}
```

For example. Only in case your mocks and ids are mapped in the same order.